# Cron Disrupting VBoxManage Commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, virtualbox, cron

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 desktop, running Virtualbox 6.1 and I use Webmin to run a very simple cron job to take daily snapshots of my virtualbox test server as follows:

`VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot"`

If I run the command from terminal, it executes without error.

**Problem:**
However, if I place the raw command into a Webmin cron job and/or inside bash wrapper script, then into a cron job,  the command will -**repeatedly**- execute over the course of an hour. deleting/creating/deleting/creating snapshots.

**Question:**
Does anyone know why the command above freaks out when executed as a cron job?

**Additional Info:**
As the command appears in the crontab.

```
* 5 * * * VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday
```

output of `grep "VboxManage" /var/log/syslog`:

```
Oct 19 05:00:01 timbuktu CRON[495412]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:01:01 timbuktu CRON[496151]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:02:01 timbuktu CRON[496962]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:03:01 timbuktu CRON[498024]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:04:01 timbuktu CRON[498782]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:05:01 timbuktu CRON[499619]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:06:01 timbuktu CRON[500360]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:07:01 timbuktu CRON[501272]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:08:01 timbuktu CRON[502180]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:09:01 timbuktu CRON[503025]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:10:01 timbuktu CRON[503871]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:11:01 timbuktu CRON[504641]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:12:01 timbuktu CRON[505454]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:13:01 timbuktu CRON[506230]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:14:02 timbuktu CRON[507093]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:15:01 timbuktu CRON[507930]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:16:01 timbuktu CRON[508710]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:17:01 timbuktu CRON[509551]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:18:01 timbuktu CRON[510372]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:19:01 timbuktu CRON[511188]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:20:01 timbuktu CRON[512150]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:21:01 timbuktu CRON[512931]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:22:01 timbuktu CRON[513723]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:23:01 timbuktu CRON[514696]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:24:01 timbuktu CRON[515473]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:25:01 timbuktu CRON[516221]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:26:01 timbuktu CRON[517063]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:27:01 timbuktu CRON[517790]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:28:01 timbuktu CRON[518548]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:29:01 timbuktu CRON[519292]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:30:01 timbuktu CRON[520023]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:31:01 timbuktu CRON[520797]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:32:01 timbuktu CRON[521771]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:33:01 timbuktu CRON[522523]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:34:01 timbuktu CRON[523264]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:35:01 timbuktu CRON[523976]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:36:01 timbuktu CRON[524757]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:37:01 timbuktu CRON[525540]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:38:01 timbuktu CRON[526225]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:39:01 timbuktu CRON[526942]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:40:01 timbuktu CRON[527681]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:41:01 timbuktu CRON[528440]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:42:02 timbuktu CRON[529212]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:43:01 timbuktu CRON[530342]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:44:01 timbuktu CRON[531348]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:45:01 timbuktu CRON[532135]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:46:01 timbuktu CRON[533003]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:47:01 timbuktu CRON[533827]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:48:01 timbuktu CRON[534843]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:49:01 timbuktu CRON[535601]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:50:01 timbuktu CRON[536361]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:51:01 timbuktu CRON[537130]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:52:01 timbuktu CRON[537885]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:53:01 timbuktu CRON[538610]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:54:01 timbuktu CRON[539426]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:55:01 timbuktu CRON[540166]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:56:01 timbuktu CRON[540892]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:57:01 timbuktu CRON[541619]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:58:01 timbuktu CRON[542368]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
Oct 19 05:59:01 timbuktu CRON[543089]: (root) CMD (VBoxManage snapshot VminServer delete "TEST - Daily Snapshot" && VBoxManage snapshot VminServer take "TEST - Daily Snapshot" #This script deletes re-creates a snapshot of Test server everyday)
```

No errors... just a repeating command.

Comment: Without the content of the cronjob, and its log output, it would be guesswork. Please include them in your question.

Comment: @mashuptwice  I added the conjob as it appears in crontab and the syslogs related to the execution of the cronjob...

Comment: Well, you told cron to run the command every minute if the hour = 5. What you want to do instead is `0 5 * * *`, which runs it if h=5 and m=0. Check https://crontab.guru for more insights.

Comment: whoops... :-/  ... thanks   rookie error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make it run every minute at 5 a clock in the morning. Change this:

```
* 5 * * * VBoxManage ...
```

to this

```
0 5 * * * VBoxManage ...
```